# Html variable for standard properties in angular

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have a table like that. And property of the table is the same for all pages in my angular project. And everywhere I must write all of them.

```
      <p-table #dtStudents [value]="Students" autoLayout="true" 
    dataKey="id" [resizableColumns]="true" [reorderableColumns]="true" [paginator]="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" [lazy]="true" 
    [responsive]="true" [rows]="10" [columns]="ch.getDataTableInfo().selectedColumns" [totalRecords]="ch.getDataTableInfo().totalRecords" 
[loading]="ch.getDataTableInfo().loading" [rowsPerPageOptions]="ch.globals.pageSizeOptions">
        </p-table>
```

But, I want like something like that.

```
 <p-table #dtStudents [value]="Students" [[[StandardProperties]]]>
 </p-table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: what about content in the table? you want it to be different on different pages?

Comment: you can do create a component with all configurations. that component have only one input -> [value]="Students" and import that component any where you want.

Comment: There will be <tr> and <td>'s in table. And will change in every page. When i create component where i can write <tr> and <td>s. Because they are different for all page.

Answer (score 1):

Make a reusable component. The HTML of your reusable component will look like this:

```
<p-table #dtStudents [value]="value" autoLayout="true" dataKey="id" [resizableColumns]="true" [reorderableColumns]="true" [paginator]="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" [lazy]="true" [responsive]="true" [rows]="10" [columns]="ch.getDataTableInfo().selectedColumns" [totalRecords]="ch.getDataTableInfo().totalRecords" [loading]="ch.getDataTableInfo().loading" [rowsPerPageOptions]="ch.globals.pageSizeOptions">
</p-table>
```

And the controller will accept one @Input like this:

```
@Input() value;
```

Then use your reusable component like this:

```
<app-reusable-component [value]="Students"></app-reusable-component>
```

Of course, the controller of the reusable component will need to do some extra work like making 'ch' available but you get the idea.

Comment: <app-reusable-component [value]="Students"></app-reusable-component>. When write like this, how can i add <tr> and <td>'s. @danday74

Comment: You can use an *ngFor inside the reusable component to iterate if you want to create table rows based on data passed in - I'm not familiar with p-table so not sure how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Management of this is very difficult. I looked for like in my question. But, i understand that angular haven't got like this feature.

Comment: I assume table rows are coming from ch whatever that is - you can declare ch in your reusable component controller code

Comment: There are a lot of different buttons in grid. And they go different function. So, I will take method and buttons dynamically. But, It will be difficult.

Comment: @HasanOzdemir use `<ng-content></ng-content>`, put it between the `p-table` tags. This way, if you add tr and td in your reusable component, it will be transferred directly to the library.

Comment: Yes as @trichetriche suggested, you might be able to use content projection to simplify your life - see https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/content-projection/ - but hard to know without fully understanding what you are trying to do

Comment: @danday74 [PrimeNG tables](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table), what he uses, allows you to create tables through their table component with `ng-content` (You get used to libraries after seeing their tags 100 times a day !)

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking for @trichetriche. This will solve my problem easily. Thanks a lot. Save my time.

Comment: If you can write as solution i will mark as solution. Or I will write. I can't mark comment as answer.